How to Search in a Nested TreeView with ItemsSource?
i have a treeView which i loaded data with ItemsSource like this:
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<FileSystemItem> items = new ObservableCollection<FileSystemItem>();

private async Task LoadFolder(string folderPath, ObservableCollection<FileSystemItem> parentCollection)
{
    foreach (string directoryPath in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath))
    {
        var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
        
        var directoryNode = new FileSystemItem(directoryInfo);
        await LoadFolder(directoryPath, directoryNode.Children);
        parentCollection.Add(directoryNode);
    }

    foreach (string filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath))
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        var fileNode = new FileSystemItem(fileInfo);
            parentCollection.Add(fileNode);
    }
}

now, i want to search in my treeview, i am using following code:
Items = new(Search(query, _backupItems));

public IEnumerable<FileSystemItem> Search(string query, ObservableCollection<FileSystemItem> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.DisplayName.Contains(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            yield return node;
        }

        foreach (var result in Search(query, node.Children))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}

but there is 2 issues:
1.after searching and removing text from textbox ItemTemplaceSelector uses a wrong template!
2.i want to show every searched item in its parent folder, currently all searched items added into treeview root level.

UPDATE 1:
This is a sample repo
App5.zip
First of all change folder path (please create a folder with some sub folders which contains some ttf,otf or woff files.
)
await LoadFilesAndFolders(@"D:\Applications\Font");


UPDATE 2:
i used following codes and it seems that everything is working fine.
public void OnAutoSuggestBoxTextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var query = sender.Text.ToLower();

    // Apply filter to the main collection
    advancedCollectionView.Filter = item =>
    {
        var fileSystemItem = item as FileSystemItem;
        if (fileSystemItem == null) return false;
        return FilterItems(fileSystemItem, query);
    };

    // Apply filter to children of each item in the main collection
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        ApplyFilterToItem(item, query);
    }
}

private void ApplyFilterToItem(FileSystemItem item, string query)
{
    item.MyChildren.Filter = childItem =>
    {
        var childFileSystemItem = childItem as FileSystemItem;
        if (childFileSystemItem == null) return false;
        return FilterItems(childFileSystemItem, query);
    };

    // Recursively apply the filter to each child
    foreach (var child in item.Children)
    {
        ApplyFilterToItem(child, query);
    }
}
bool FilterItems(FileSystemItem item, string query)
{
    // Check if the item matches the query
    if (item.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(query))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Recursively check if any child item matches the query
    foreach (var child in item.Children)
    {
        if (FilterItems(child, query))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT i added a sample repo in my first post

Did you mean this?

I make a little change on your code but note OnAutoSuggestBoxTextChanged need rewriting for the general condition.
I use one more AdvancedCollectionView for children based on your application design.
public class FileSystemItem
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<FileSystemItem> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<FileSystemItem>();
    public AdvancedCollectionView MyChildren { get; } = new AdvancedCollectionView();
  
    public FileSystemItem(FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo)
    {
        ...
        MyChildren = new AdvancedCollectionView(Children, true);
    }
}

XAML
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.advancedCollectionView, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:FileSystemItem">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyChildren}">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DisplayName}" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>

The Code behind
    public void OnAutoSuggestBoxTextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    advancedCollectionView.Filter = _ => true;
    advancedCollectionView.Filter = item =>
    {
        var node = (FileSystemItem)item;
        var name = node.DisplayName ?? "";

        // Check if the current node matches the search text
        if (name.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if (node.HasChildren)
        {
            node.MyChildren.Filter = _ => true;
            node.MyChildren.Filter = item =>
            {
                var node = (FileSystemItem)item;
                var name = node.DisplayName ?? "";

                // Check if the current node matches the search text
                if (name.Contains(sender.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;

                //TODO rewrite the code. This is Just for example.
            };
            if (node.MyChildren.Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Check if any child node matches the search text
        //foreach (var child in node.Children)
        //{
        //    if (FilterRecursive(child, sender.Text))
        //        return true;
        //}

        // If none of the current node or its children match, return false
        return false;

    };
}

Update with the more general code example.
private string _theFilterString;
public void OnAutoSuggestBoxTextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    _theFilterString = sender.Text;
    advancedCollectionView.Filter = _ => true;
    advancedCollectionView.Filter = MyFilter;
}

bool MyFilter(object item)
{
    var node = (FileSystemItem)item;
    var name = node.DisplayName ?? "";

    if (name.Contains(_theFilterString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (node.HasChildren)
    {
        node.MyChildren.Filter = _ => true;
        node.MyChildren.Filter = MyFilter;
        if (node.MyChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


tnx, there is some issues, first, issue is when you remove search words, items expander gone and we cant expand it again. and second issue is it seems that only folder searched and files skipped.

i added my new search codes in my first post (Update 2) which is working fine now. Can you check to see if my code is optimized? And can it be simpler or have less repetitive operations

@Chibako I have updated with the more general code example.
